# Navigation Stack in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Can I view the contents of the navigation stack? Will I be able to display the stack contents on the terminal, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  UINavigationController has a viewControllers property that returns the nav stack.  You can view this in your console by setting a breakpoint in one of your view controllers and typing this at the gdb prompt:

```
po [[self navigationController] viewControllers]
```